# How to resize externel image URL

Tags: javascript, image, canvas

I am using ionic 2.

I displayed list of images using ngFor.

Images are diff height and width.

Here is my sample externel URL.

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/apartments-ea9e5.appspot.com/o/album%2Fb9.jpg?alt=media&token=b7d754cc-bc57-4bc2-b9a9-f93f3dbda27d

I need resize this image.

Now i get this Image width and height.

Here is my fun

```
 var someImage="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/apartments-ea9e5.appspot.com/o/album%2Fb9.jpg?alt=media&token=b7d754cc-bc57-4bc2-b9a9-f93f3dbda27d;
 var img = new Image();
 img.src = someImage;
 img.addEventListener("load", function(){
       console.log( this.naturalWidth +' '+ this.naturalHeight );
 });
```

How can i resize this image without canvas.Because canvas Result returned base64string.I dont need base64string.

can u help me..

Comment: resize the image to what size?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.width and height 500px

Comment: I have Multiple Images ...