# Does not resize image

Tags: javascript, jquery, image-resizing

here is my URL

https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/apartments-ea9e5.appspot.com/o/bulletinboard%2Fsample-1494577677180.jpg?alt=media&token=7a0c1ff0-1bc7-4ea9-9176-072aacc4349c

This image height and width is 225 & 400

i need height and width 100

here is javascript function

```
var myUrl = 'https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/apartments-ea9e5.appspot.com/o/bulletinboard%2Fsample-1494577677180.jpg?alt=media&token=7a0c1ff0-1bc7-4ea9-9176-072aacc4349c';

    var img = new Image();
    img.src = myUrl;
    var width;
    var height;
    img.addEventListener("load", function(){
         console.log( this.naturalWidth +' '+ this.naturalHeight )
         var imagewidth=this.naturalWidth;
         var imageheight=this.naturalHeight;
         var maxht =100;
         var maxwt = 100;
         if (imageheight > maxht || imagewidth > maxwt) 
         {
           var old_ratio = imageheight / imagewidth;
           var min_ratio = maxht / maxwt;
            // If it can scale perfectly.
            if (old_ratio === min_ratio) {
              // this.resize_image(img, maxht, maxwt);
              console.log(old_ratio);
              console.log(min_ratio);
              img.height = maxht;
              img.width  = maxwt;
              console.log("does not change height and width");
              console.log(img.src);
            }
             else {
            var newdim = [imageheight, imagewidth];
            newdim[0] = maxht;  // Sort out the height first
            // ratio = ht / wt => wt = ht / ratio.
            var old_ratio = imageheight / imagewidth;
            newdim[1] = newdim[0] / old_ratio;
            // Do we still have to sort out the width?
            if (newdim[1] > maxwt) {
              newdim[1] = maxwt;
              newdim[0] = newdim[1] * old_ratio;
            }
            //this.resize_image(img, newdim[0], newdim[1]);
            img.height = newdim[0];
            img.width  = newdim[1];
            console.log("change heigth and width");
            console.log(img.src);
            }


         }


         // width=this.naturalWidth;
         // height=this.naturalHeight;
    });
```

But does not change the height and width.

Kindly advice me,
Thanks

Comment: Why you don't use CSS or resize the image then?

Comment: Thanks for ur reply.I change css but not wrk properly

Comment: OK, I did that both CSS and Javascript way for you... look at the answer

Answer (score 0):

You can do this using only css properties.Below is a code sample.

Hope it will be useful

```css
img {
  max-width: 100px;
  max-height: 100px;
}
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/apartments-ea9e5.appspot.com/o/bulletinboard%2Fsample-1494577677180.jpg?alt=media&token=7a0c1ff0-1bc7-4ea9-9176-072aacc4349c">
  <div>
```

Comment: Thanks.i need responsive image on mobile devices.I have multiple images.so i need resize image.

Answer (score 0):

You can just use CSS to resize your image, something like this:

```
img {
    width: 100px;
    height: 100px;
}
```

Always CSS first, if you couldn't solve it this way, then find a JavaScript way to solve it..

in JavaScript do it this way(as example), you can refine the code as suite you:

```
function resizeIMG(w, h){
  var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img'), i=0;

  while(img.length > i) {
    img[i].style.width = w + 'px';
    img[i].style.height = h + 'px';
    i++;
  }
}
```

and call it like this:

```
resizeIMG(100, 100);
```

```js
function resizeIMG(w, h) {
  var img = document.getElementsByTagName('img'),
    i = 0;

  while (img.length > i) {
    img[i].style.width = w + 'px';
    img[i].style.height = h + 'px';
    i++;
  }
}

resizeIMG(100, 100);
```

```html
<div>
  <img src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/apartments-ea9e5.appspot.com/o/bulletinboard%2Fsample-1494577677180.jpg?alt=media&token=7a0c1ff0-1bc7-4ea9-9176-072aacc4349c">
<div>
```

Comment: Thanks.But I have multiple images.display on mobile devices with responsive.because i need images are same height.and also i write on css.width:100%;heigth:auto

Comment: Man, then your question is not clear, you said you height and width at 100

Comment: It can be refine to do your job with some extra line... let me compare it with your code

Comment: Thanks for ur patient.Kindly pls refer this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/44089187/how-to-resize-externel-image-url.

Answer (score 0):

You can do this by writing this simple structure and css without stretching the image

```css
.box {
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  overflow: hidden;
  display: inline-block;
}

img {
  max-width: 100%;
  height: auto;
}
```

```html
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/apartments-ea9e5.appspot.com/o/bulletinboard%2Fsample-1494577677180.jpg?alt=media&token=7a0c1ff0-1bc7-4ea9-9176-072aacc4349c" />
</div>
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/apartments-ea9e5.appspot.com/o/bulletinboard%2Fsample-1494577677180.jpg?alt=media&token=7a0c1ff0-1bc7-4ea9-9176-072aacc4349c">
</div>
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/apartments-ea9e5.appspot.com/o/bulletinboard%2Fsample-1494577677180.jpg?alt=media&token=7a0c1ff0-1bc7-4ea9-9176-072aacc4349c">
</div>
<div class="box">
  <img src="https://firebasestorage.googleapis.com/v0/b/apartments-ea9e5.appspot.com/o/bulletinboard%2Fsample-1494577677180.jpg?alt=media&token=7a0c1ff0-1bc7-4ea9-9176-072aacc4349c">
</div>
```